# PHP conditional statement is not working

Tags: php, html, drupal-7

I have a statement that checks the page's url and marks up a page accordingly, but it only works when my if statement has one option to check for.

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

<?php if (strpos($url, 'events/eventname')!= false) { ?>
    ~markup~
<? } ?>
```

If I modify it to check for two possible urls...

```
<?php if (strpos($url, 'events/eventname')!= false) { ?>
    ~markup~
<? }else if (strpos($url, 'events/othereventname')!= false) { ?>
    ~markup~
<? } ?>
```

... the page won't load. I must be missing something obvious- can someone tell me what is wrong with this function?

*edit: Since it was requested I have included the $url variable and more specific url examples

Comment: Where is URL defined? And also, what are those "urlhere" or "otherurlher"? These informations may usefull for devs to understand your code.

Comment: Try !== instead of !=. Regarding PHP documentation: Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: @Ad5001 Gameur codeur autre
URL is defined elsewhere in the code- I didn't include it or the actual urls (which I substituted with urlhere and otherurlhere) because it wasn't directly relevant to the problem.

Comment: I agree that some more realistic examples for `$url` and `'urlhere'` could be helpful here. I don't necessarily agree that it isn't directly relevant to the problem.

Comment: I think it looks like you might have the arguments to `strpos` backward, but without really seeing what's what, that's just a guess.

Comment: Is that to say that instead of (strpos($url, 'events/eventname')!= false), I should use (strpos('events/eventname', $url)!=false)?

Comment: Nope, now that I see what's there, my theory was wrong. ;)

Comment: I thick posting what `echo $url;` outputs would help.

Comment: In a way, others are correct to recommend using `!==` instead of `!=` for the `strpos` comparison, because zero will evalute to false, _but_ in this case it shouldn't matter since you're appending `'http://'` to the beginning of `$url`, so the strpos should never be zero. I can't reproduce the error. Your code seems to work as intended on my system.

Comment: Is it possible that your $url doesnt contain neither 'events/eventname' and 'events/othereventname' ?

Comment: I have confirmed that echoing $url prints the current page url, which I would rather not share.

Comment: Is there more PHP code inside the second if, or just HTML? If the page won't load, it could be because code in the second if is causing an error.

Comment: No, @Don'tPanic. What I have done is split the check into two separate functions and now the pages load properly.

Answer (score 2):

strpos returns 0 when search substring is in the beginning of the query string. You can replace != to !== to make it work - otherwise php is internally transforming false to zero, which leads to incorrect comparison result.

For example:

```
<?php
var_dump(strpos('aaa', 'a'));
echo var_dump(strpos('aaa', 'a') === false);
echo var_dump(strpos('aaa', 'a') == false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `!==` comparison just just in case string is at position 0.

Another syntax problem is `else if`, while you should use `elseif`.

Try also changing short php tag `<?` to full one `<?php`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris Cynarski but neither of those corrections solved the problem.

Comment: Try using full php tags `<?php` instead of short one `<?`.

Comment: If short tags weren't enabled, the first one wouldn't have worked either.

Answer (score -2):

Rather than using the `strpos()` you can get the request uri which is anything after the domain name (ie: www.example.com/foo/bar would give you /foo/bar).

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($url == "/foo/bar") {
    // markup
} elseif($url == "/bar/foo") {
    // markup
} else {
    // markup
}
```